# Detecting heartbeat failure

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos

I have 2 Centos machines sending heartbeat every 1 minute over certain port, I want to monitor when this heartbeat is not received on any node, anyone know how to achieve this using bash or any other script ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add (a _lot_) more detail. You need to tell us exactly what kind of signal you're sending, how you are receiving it, what kind of setup this is (are the nodes on the same cluster? On the same network? Different machines? Different networks?). The more detail you give us, the better your chances of getting useful answers. Also, please show us what you have tried so far so we don't repeat the work you have already done.

Comment: Plus, this sounds like a job for daemon that I'd probably rather not write in shell script.

Comment: How are you "sending heartbeat"? Have you installed any HA (high-availability) tools? Try `man heartbeat`.